# 部分ビューのインデントを調整するには

Tags: asp.net, razor

```
<body>
  @Html.Partial("_Partial1")
</body>

_Partial1.cshtml  
<h1>Partial1</h1>
<div>
  @Html.Partial("_Partial2")
</div>

_Partial2.cshtml
<h2>Partial2</h2>
<p>これはサンプルです。</p>
```

部分ビューを使って、上のようなページを作成した場合、
出力されるhtmlは以下のようなものになります。（インデントが崩れている）

```
<body>
  <h1>Partial1</h1>
<div>
  <h2>Partial2</h2>
<p>これはサンプルです。</p>
</div>
</body>
```

これを以下のように適切なインデントが設定された出力にすることは可能でしょうか？

```
<body>
  <h1>Partial1</h1>
  <div>
    <h2>Partial2</h2>
    <p>これはサンプルです。</p>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: 出来ないような気がしていますが、目的の様なものはありますか？

Comment: 出力結果のhtmlを人に説明する時や、テスト時のエビデンスや検証などが目的です。適切にインデントされているほうが見やすいので。

Comment: エビデンスはなるべく出力そのままの方がいいでしょうから難しいかもしれませんが、ほかのケースであれば整形してくれるツールを挟むという手もありますね。その一手間が省略できた方がいいのだとは思いますが。
最近のブラウザなら開発者ツール（IEならDOMExplorer）で見る分には自動整形してくれていると思います。